# If a set is open in one metric it is open in another?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Ive been struggling to grasp a certain situation involving metric spaces and was wondering if anyone could be of any help. In the notes for my module on metric spaces I have the following

> "If two metrics $d$ and $d′$ on $X$ satisfy $$hd′(x,y) \le d(x,y) \le kd′(x,y)$$ for any $x, y \in X$, then their respective open balls satisfy $B_{hε}(x) \subseteq B_{ε′}(x)$ and $B′_{ε/k} (x) \subseteq B_ε(x)$."

where $B_{hε}(x)$ means the open ball $B$ of radius $hε$ around $x$.

I can prove that such cases are true but can't understand intuitively why each ball is contained in the other in such a way, it feels like almost the opposite should be true. Usually some sort of picture is enough to make intuitive sense of the situation but I wouldn't know where to start here.

Could someone possibly show how we could observe that the above containments are true, prior to being given them?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you know that $hd′(x,y) \le d(x,y) \le kd′(x,y)$. Let's start reasoning just from that premise.

This means that if $d'(x,y) < a$ then $d(x,y) \le kd'(x,y) < ka$.

So if $y \in B'_{a}(x)$ (which is the first condition), we know that $y \in B_{ka}(x)$ (which is the conclusion). Hence for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we know that $B'_{\varepsilon}(x) \subseteq B_{k\varepsilon}(x)$ (take $a = \varepsilon$). If you want $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ on the right hand side, take $a = \frac{\varepsilon}{k}$ so that the condition on the right becomes $d(x,y) < \varepsilon$, and then $$B'_{\frac{\varepsilon}{k}}(x) \subseteq B_{\varepsilon}(x)\text{.}$$

On the other hand, if $d(x,y) < a$ then $hd'(x,y) \le d(x,y) < a$, which implies $d'(x,y) < \frac{a}{h}$, diving both sides by $h$. This yields the ball inclusion $B_a(x) \subseteq B'_{\frac{a}{h}}(x)$ for all $a$. Again, if you $B'_{\varepsilon}(x)$, then you need $\frac{a}{h} = \varepsilon$, or $a = h\varepsilon$ and you get the required $$B_{h\varepsilon}(x) \subseteq B'_{\varepsilon}(x)\text{.}$$

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at these two metrics on $\mathbb R^2$:

$$
\|(x, y) \|_1 = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\\
\|(x, y) \|_2 = |x| + |y|
$$
Convince yourself that the "unit circle" for the first one is the usual unit circle. The "unit circle" for the second is a diamond shape with corners at $(\pm1, 0), (0, \pm 1)$.

For these two, what are the numbers $h$ and $k$?

Working through this example should give you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

From the left inequality we have $y\in B_d(x,e)$ $\implies d(y,x)<e$ $\implies d'(y,x)\leq (1/h)e\implies y\in B_d'(x,e/h).$ So $B_d(x,e)\subset B_d'(x,e/h).$ Similarly for the right-hand inequality, which we can write as  $d'(x,y)\leq  (1/k)d(x,y).$

This is called uniform equivalence of the metrics. Equivalence of metrics means they generate the same topology.  On $\mathbb R,$ let $e(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $e'(x,y)=\min (|x-y|,1).$ Then $e,e'$ are equivalent but not uniformly equivalent.

The topology on a metrizable space is uniquely determined by the set of convergent sequences, because convergent sequences in a metric space determine the closures of subsets..... Let $d,d'$ be uniformly equivalent metrics. Then obviously $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(y_n,x)=0\iff \lim_{n\to \infty}d'(y_n,x)=0.$ So $d,d'$ generate the same topology. ....  Consider that the set $B$ of open $d$-balls and the set $B'$ of open $d'$-balls are therefore both bases for the same topology. So if $U$ is open and $x\in U,$ then (i) $x\in b\subset U$ for some $b\in B,$ and  (ii) $x\in b'\subset U$ for some $b'\in B'$. Now picture this  when  (i) $U\in B'$ and (ii) $U\in B.$